# Shared hosting - force mail return envelope

Tags: emails

I hope I'm on the right site, because it's a crossover between drupal and server configuration...

I am currently using shared hosting for a website and am encountering mail problems while sending mails from the website (drupal CMS). The problem is I only host the website, the mail server is located with another host causing the mails to their own domain to be dropped.

Basically I have example.com and I'm trying to send an email to john.doe@example.com from drupal. To avoid having the mail dropped and to avoid changes on the example.com mailserver side I would prefer to send mails from website2.com which is hosted on the same server.

According to my host I should use the "-f" option of the PHP mail() function to force my website.com e-mailaddress, but I cannot believe this is required since this is not supported by the Drupal core. I cannot be the only one in this scenario, yet I do not find any solution. Can somebody point me in the right direction ?

Technical information:

- Running Installatron
- Shared hosting with two domains: example.com and website2.com
- External mailserver, dns is managed by other host.

Comment: Since you're not the system administrator your question may technically be off-topic here. But, if Drupal uses the simple PHP `mail()` command maybe you can set `php_admin_value sendmail_path "/usr/sbin/sendmail -ffrom@website2.com -t -i"` in your .htaccess file to force the envelope sender.

Comment: Hi, tx for your help. I've tried and google't it, but according to the docs php_admin_value can not be set via .htaccess.

Comment: Have you looked into the [SMTP](https://www.drupal.org/project/smtp) module?